# Django can't find redirect url when authenticating user

Tags: django, authentication, django-urls, python-decorators

I am trying to login protect some of my pages, including my dashboard. Here is the view for my dashboard at the root of my site: sitename.com/

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    print(request.session['user_email'])
    context_dict = {}

    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context_dict)
```

My project url file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^job/', include('job.urls')),
    url(r'^welcome/', include('welcome.urls')), //the app for logging in
    url(r'^$', include('dashboard.urls')), //main dashboard app
    # s

]
```

My dashboard app url file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.auth_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

When I try and logout and then go to / I get a message saying that http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome?next=/ doesn't match any urls in my project urls file. So the login check is working, it just can't figure out the url when the GET variable next is set.

Comment: url(r'^$', include('dashboard.urls')),    this is wrong way to use doller $ with given urls file location. Using $ doller dashboard url will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. This is my routes:

Welcome app routes (app for logging in/out)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^/login/$', views.auth_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^/logout', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Main routes for the entire project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^welcome', include('welcome.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('dashboard.urls')),

]
```

Now I don't get any errors with the next variable in the url:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome?next=/

I have a javascript file grabbing the value of next and redirecting to it if the user logs in successfully. *I use ajax to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using django's default login from contrib.auth, try passing `next as an extra_context dict`.

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html', 'extra_context': {'next':'/'}})
```

Another solution is to specify login url in login_required decorator itself

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
print(request.session['user_email'])
context_dict = {}

return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context_dict)
```

Let know if this solve your issue. HTH :)